# iterate through pandas dataframe consecutive columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a loop in pandas to calculate difference between consecutive columns and give output in a new column:

Original df:

```
**201601** **201602** **201603**  
100           200         500
```

Desired output

```
**201601** **201602** **201603**  **201602_201601** **201603_02**
100           200         500         100          300
```

My code is which I had modified from a stackoverflow post ([[add columns to a data frame calculated by for loops in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36830232/add-columns-to-a-data-frame-calculated-by-for-loops-in-python][1])):

```
for i in df.iloc[:,2:5]:
  for j in df.iloc[:,2:5]:
    if i == j:
        break
    else:
        bina = df[i]-df[j]
        df['MOM_' + str(j) + '_' + str(i)] = bina
df.head()
```

However, the output I get is as below:

```
**201601** **201602** **201603**  **201602_201601** **201603_201601** **201603_201602**
100           200         500         100          400   300
```

I have used pd.diff to do what I needed but couldn't figure out the for loop code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The `for` loop is the _opposite_ direction to what you probably want to go. If you want to iterate the dataframe then you, probably, don't want to have a dataframe at all. You should be trying to look for vectorized approaches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just fix your code

```
col=df.columns
for x,i in enumerate(col):
    for y,j in enumerate(col):
        if  y-x==1 and i!=j:
            bina = df[i]-df[j]
            df['MOM_' + str(j) + '_' + str(i)] = bina
df.columns
Out[1210]: 
Index(['**201601**', '**201602**', '**201603**', 'MOM_**201602**_**201601**',
       'MOM_**201603**_**201602**'],
      dtype='object')
```

Comment: Thanks W-B for the prompt response. The code worked for me after a slight modification. However, could you please elaborate what the code is doing when checking 'y-x'==1.

Comment: @vagautam that is make sure only the continue input being calculated

Answer (score 2):

Using `diff` and simple list comprehension with `zip` to construct the columns' names.

```
cols = [f'{b}_{a}' for (a,b) in zip(df.columns, df.columns[1:])]
df[cols] = df.diff(axis=1).dropna(axis=1)

    201601  201602  201603  201602_201601   201603_201602
0   100     200     500     100             300
```

Avoid to use `for` loops at all times when using pandas

Comment: You were the first, I concede.